# 'import jwt' not working in Django views.py though I have PyJwt installed

Tags: python, django, jwt, pyjwt

I'm working with Django and trying to generate **jwt tokens** in views.py and displaying it in html page.
**import jwt** is throwing **No module found error** in *views.py* even though I have **PyJwt** installed already inside the virtual environment and it is working fine outside the views.py *(say, jwttoken.py file)*

**views.py**

```
import jwt
def generateJWT(portal):
    key = 'secret'
    payload =  {'iat': time.time(),
                'iss' : 'localhost',
                'exp': int(time.time()) + (5*365*24 * 60),
                'portal': portal}  
    #return payload
    return jwt.encode(payload, key, algorithm="HS256")
```

Does it mean that I can't make use of jwt module in django? Is there any other way to make it work in Django as it is working outside?

Comment: I think you installed both "jwt" and "PyJWT" .It is not recommended to have both the "jwt" and "PyJWT" packages installed at the same time because they may cause conflicts with each other. You may want to try uninstalling the "jwt" package to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes I did face issue before because of this. Then I uninstalled JWT and have only PyJwt with me. And also it is working fine outside the views.py function (I mean I am able to generate tokens successfully in jwttoken.py)

Answer (score 0):

[jwt](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/) and [PyJWT](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/) are two different modules. They are both imported with "import jwt", so they can conflict with each other.

Check which JWT module you have installed. If you have both try removing one of them.

See also: [PyJWT won't import jwt.algorithms (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt.algorithms')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128255/pyjwt-wont-import-jwt-algorithms-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-jwt-alg)

Comment: Yes I did face issue before because of this. Then I uninstalled JWT and have only PyJwt with me. And also it is working fine outside the **views.py** function (I mean I am able to generate tokens successfully in **jwttoken.py**)

Answer (score 0):

u can check it by running 'pip freeze' in terminal to check if its installed or not, if 'jwt' is not listed then it means its not available in your pj. Or you can try import pyjwt instead of import jwt to check whether if its working or not.

Otherwise, there might be a problem with django project itself. make sure u activate the exact environment.

Comment: Yes tried everything. But it is not working inside views.py file only