# AttributeError: module 'jwt.algorithms' has no attribute 'hashes'

Tags: python, docker, pip, jwt, attributeerror

I try to run the following script in a Python virtual environment by having pyjwt installed with `pip3 install -U pyjwt` as per [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128255/pyjwt-wont-import-jwt-algorithms-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-jwt-alg) and it works

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_RSA

headerauth = OAuth1(client_key, rsa_key, signature_type="auth_header", signature_method=SIGNATURE_RSA)
r = requests.get(url, auth=headerauth)
```

However, it's throwing an error when I try to run the local Docker image

```
AttributeError: module 'jwt.algorithms' has no attribute 'hashes'
```

The versions stated in Pipfile are same as those in Python virtual environment

```
[packages]
pyjwt = ">=2.8.0"
requests-oauthlib = ">=1.3.1"
```

Comment: check package `cryptography` in requirement before build image.

Comment: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/1096 Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=AttributeError+%22module+jwt.algorithms+has+no+attribute+hashes%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `cryptography` should solve this issue:

```
pip install -U cryptography
```